# How to restore original MailItem of an Inspector?

Tags: c++, outlook-addin

I'm changing the body of a `MailItem` object associated with an `Inspector`, and I would like to restore the original state.  Currently I'm saving the original content (i.e., email body, subject, etc) and setting it back again, but whenever a user closes the `Inspector` he is presented with a dialog asking if he wants to save changes.  Does anyone know if there's a way to restore the original `MailItem`without having to present the user with a dialog asking if he wants to save it?

Comment: Intercept the close event of the mailitem and resolve the save.  Example in the close event MSDN article.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-close-event-outlook

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. If you need to display data different from what is stored in Outlook, create a form region, task pane, or a custom message form. Resetting/restoring is a hack that will break at the worst possible moment.

Comment: Is there any reason why `MailItem` bodies shouldn't be changed, particularly if changes aren't saved?

Comment: Yes, because a user or Outlook can save your temporary changes. You can try to work around that, but it will be a losing game.

Comment: thanks for the input.  That does explain how some changes I was making in some mail bodies were being made permanent without calling save.  Do you happen to have any reference that explains how Outlook saves temporary changes?

Comment: It automatically saves changes on a timer after a minute or two.

Comment: That's a tad inconvenient.  Is there any way to disable that timer?

Comment: Nope. Don't try to fight Outlook - you will lose :-)